# Second External IP for exchange email

Tags: exchange

My office added a second ISP (Comcast fiber). I'm in the process of changing the major services to the fiber.

Do I need to change anything on my server for a new external IP. The firewall is set to forward 25 from the fiber to the box.

Also, could I use this as failover of sorts if I set 2 different DNS records, one to each external ip?

Thanks

Comment: A failover for ... what? Do you have a public SSL certificate? Webmail, Activesync, Autodiscover? Are you running this through one firewall/router or two? You don't want incoming traffic via one address and return traffic going out via the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a link balancer to make use of the additional ISP link. Consider something like the [Elfiq load balancer](http://elfiq.com/products) because it can balance outbound *and* inbound traffic...

But to answer your immediate question, you should check:

- Your MX records. Make sure they point to the desired incoming link.
- If you have any spam filtering inline, make sure that's aware of your IP change.
- Chances are that your two external IPs don't have the same destination. Of course, this depends on your gateway/firewall device. We're missing those details.
- What about Exchange mobile access and Autodiscover DNS records?
- Do you use Outlook Web Access?
- You may want to establish reverse-DNS records for your new IP space.
- Also create or update your SPF records to make sure the new IP space is accounted for.